# How to style an img tag in javascript/jquery after finding a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a wordpress/php website in which I want to style an img tag after finding a div in javascript/jquery.

The HTML code where things need to happen is:

```
<div class="page-hero page-hero--reports cf">
   <figure class="page-hero__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <img src="">       // where opacity:0.7 needs to be apllied.  
   </figure>
   <div class="page-hero__content-contain">
      <h2 class="page-hero__title-top page-hero__title--heavy">Trans Mountain Pipeline: NEB Releases New Report, Recommends Approval </h2>
      <h2 class="page-hero__title-bottom page-hero__title--heavy"> More Coverage</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is what I have tried but it doesn't work.

```
$(".page-hero--reports").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find(".page-hero__title-top").not(":empty").length > 0 && $(this).find(".page-hero__title-bottom").not(":empty").length > 0) {
        $(this).find(".img-fit img").css("opacity", "0.7");
    } 
});
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the script above so that it applies a style on an img tag on page-load.

Comment: Maybe just opacitty doesn't work? I had some issues with it - depends on browser.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in stacksnippet?

Comment: Or maybe the wrapper is not yet loaded for some reason? Does the console.log below work? `$(".page-hero--reports").each(function () {
console.log('got here');`

how about trying your code using the javascript console after your page is loaded

`$(".page-hero--reports").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find(".page-hero__title-top").not(":empty").length > 0 && $(this).find(".page-hero__title-bottom").not(":empty").length > 0) {
        $(this).find(".img-fit img").css("opacity", "0.7");
    } 
});`

Comment: opacity is working for me

Comment: Working just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/1py4ntrk/

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using `.each`?

How about just:

```
// find elements
$(".page-hero--reports img").css("opacity", "0.2");
```

Like so:

```js
// find elements
$(".page-hero--reports img").css("opacity", "0.2");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-hero page-hero--reports cf">
   <figure class="page-hero__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <img src="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/190311171619-sarah-sanders-0311-medium-tease.jpg">
   </figure>
   <div class="page-hero__content-contain">
      <h2 class="page-hero__title-top page-hero__title--heavy">Trans Mountain Pipeline: NEB Releases New Report, Recommends Approval </h2>
      <h2 class="page-hero__title-bottom page-hero__title--heavy"> More Coverage</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```